# Can renovate bot use the auth.json within the repository for composer packages?

Tags: composer-php, renovate

*Disclaimer:*

So we have a `auth.json` for our projects in the (private) git repository with not-so-secret credentials which are needed to set up a project.

I am copying the argument from [here](https://%20https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9920#issuecomment-851901227):

> It's common practice to add an auth.json for Enterprise software (such as Magento,
> where you have different auth keys for different projects) in the same directory as the > composer.json just to identify as authorized to download these packages (which an build > and deployment framework needs to be authorized as well), which shouldn't be an issue
> as those repositories are privately hosted anyways.
> https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9920#issuecomment-851901227

*Problem:*

When running renovate bot on such a project we get a message:

```
Failed to look up packagist package .....
Files affected: composer.json
```

I did not find a configuration option on renovate bot to use the credentials from the `auth.json` in the repository.

Instead we would have to [manually define hostRules](https://:%20https://docs.renovatebot.com/getting-started/private-packages/#composer). This would work.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-Post warning:

X-Follow-up to: https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/22818

Actually I think https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/22818  is the better place for this questions

I currently cannot delete this, because of the bounty.